# Hacer que cada DropDownList de una view sean del mismo tamaño

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una view para la creacion de una identity, y los dropdowlist son de tamaños diferentes y esteticamente no me gusta, quisiera hacer que todos los dropdowlist sean del tamaño del dropdorwlist mas largo.

Esta es la view Create.cshtml:

```
@model FitnessWebApplication.Models.Routine

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Routine</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinishDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FinishDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FinishDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimesAWeek, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimesAWeek, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimesAWeek, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArmExcercise, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArmExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.ArmsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 1")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArmExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.ArmsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 2")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArmExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.ArmsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 3")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PecExcercise, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PecExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.PecsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 1")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PecExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.PecsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 2")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PecExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.PecsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 3")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AbdominalExcercise, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AbdominalExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.AbdominalsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 1")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AbdominalExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.AbdominalsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 2")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AbdominalExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.AbdominalsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 3")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BackExcercise, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BackExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.BackExcercises))), "Select Excersice 1")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BackExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.BackExcercises))), "Select Excersice 2")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BackExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.BackExcercises))), "Select Excersice 3")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LegExcercise, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LegExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.LegsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 1")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LegExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.LegsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 2")</td>
                <td align="left"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LegExcercise, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Routine.LegsExcercises))), "Select Excersice 3")</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    @using FitnessWebApplication.Models

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Por qué no le defines el tamaño a todos los dropdownlist con css,  usando un tamaño estándar sin importar cual es el más largo, algo como esto: col-md-10 pero para los dropdownlist

Comment: Entiendo, lo malo es que no recuerdo nada de CSS, pero alla voy!

Comment: @BryanRomero te recomiendo la documentación boostrap. Tu puedes.https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías generar una clase en CSS y agregarla como atributo class al DropDownList

```
.dropdownlist{
     width:150px;
}
```